# Installin R in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install R in Anaconda in order to use it in Jupyter Notebook.
I have the version of Anaconda3-4.4.0-Windows-x86_64 installed on Windows10.

I installed R package with conda run : conda install -c r r-irkernel.

Unfortunately, when I started R in Jupyter Notebook, I got message "kernel error" (picture attached).

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?[image: Kernel Error]

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need to also use this command:

```
conda install -c r r-essentials
```

Comment: already done that, but still not working. Any other solution?

Comment: I think that there should be some error in the terminal. What is it?

Comment: After running this command in the jupyter terminal, It will ask permission to download and install some other packages. Just press 'y' and then restart your Jupyter instance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to install more other packages in order to run R kernel in Jupyter, and this nice article from [Datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/jupyter-notebook-r#comments) that might help you to do so. However, as Andrey mentioned you still be able to use R env by installing 
r-essentials in current environment OR separate env

```
conda install -n my_r_env -c r r-essentials
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new environment.

> conda create -n my-r-env -c r r-essentials